# unable to see the page. No error is being shown in console

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to create a backbone application having login page and one dashboard page called home so for that I have created router having two routes.

After login, I am redirecting to the dashboard page

But I am not seeing anything at all when I run index file.
In the console also, no error is being shown.

```js
var AppRoute = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "":        "login",  // #search/kiwis
    "home": "home"
  },

  login: function(){
   var loginTemplate = _.template($('#loginPage_template').html());
 $('#htmlBodyContent').html(loginTemplate({}));
 $('#somlogin').click(function(e) {
    var loginData= {};
 loginData.userName=document.getElementById('userName').value;
 loginData.password=document.getElementById('password').value;
 console.log(loginData);
 if(loginData.userName==='admin' && loginData.password==='admin' ){
  console.log("login successfull")
   window.location.hash="#home"; 
 }else{
  console.log("do not match")
 }


})
  }

  home: function() {
    console.log("welcom to home")
  }

});

var router = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

        <div id="htmlBodyContent">

  </div>
<script type="text/template" id="loginPage_template">
<div class="container">
 
 <form class="login">
 <h6>dawai<h6>
 <input type="userName" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName">
 
 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
 <br>
 <button type="button" class="btn-sm" id="loginBtn" >login</button>

 </form>


</div>
</script>


<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"</script>




 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your html file: `<script src="scripts/main.js"</script>` should be `<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>`

Comment: I have fixed that still not making any difference though.

Answer (score 2):

I see you use `window.location` to navigate your application, that is the problem. You need to use Backbone router api to navigate:

```
login: function() {
  //...
    this.navigate('home', {trigger: true});
  //...
}
```